# How to "bust cache" in a SPA when the client code is already downloaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, single-page-application, durandal

I'm currently using grunt to bundle up my application into a versioned payload that busts cache between downloads.  What I'm working on now is when the *client has already downloaded the bits* and is working with cached clientside code.

1. I deploy version 1.0
2. Bob downloads v1.0
3. Cindy downloads v1.0
4. I deploy v1.1
5. Bob's cache expires, he gets v1.1 next time he visits my site
6. Cindy still has v1.0 making AJAX requests to v1.2 serverside code

I'm trying to figure out how to tell Cindy's browser on #6 - "hey!  you have old code!  Trigger a refresh!"

What I'm thinking is - somehow in the response header of every request, include the **Date and Time** of the build that the response is coming from.  But this means I need to access the properties of the DLL as part of every request.  Is this possible?

If so, then I could compare that date/time with the client's date/time (UTC, of course) to determine if a refresh is needed.

If not, what is the proper solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your require.js config you can add a urlArgs attribute:

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: 'bust=@Revision@',
    ...
    ...
});
```

This will add the revision number onto the end of the url for the requests.

You can then replace the @Revision@ with your revision number using the grunt task. If you are using something like teamcity for CI you can also do it there and replace it with the actual build number generated by teamcity You can do this with powershell.

Note that on every deployment you will force the client to get *all* javascript files regardless if they have changed or not. This may or may not be desired depending on your situation. If you wish to be a bit cleverer, you can hash the contents of the file and cache these server side, you can then create a require.js paths config which maps the client side name to the hash key. When the content of the file changes the hash changes thus forcing a new download for only the files that have changed.

Hope this helps.